# `\makebackcover` not recognized, but `texlive-collection-latexextra` is installed

Tags: packages

In my new 2020 Cygwin installation, `pdflatex` is not recognizing `\makebackcover`:

```
    <...snip...>
LaTeX Warning: Rerun to get acronym list right.

[43]
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/phv/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 5.69998pt on input line 2946.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/phv/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 6.64998pt on input line 2946.
 [44

]
! Undefined control sequence.
l.2949    \makebackcover

? X
    <...snip...>
```

A web search [reveals](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/upmethodology/doc/upmethodology-doc.pdf) that `\makebackcover` is part of the `upmethodology` package, which I already have:

```
$ tlmgr list --only-installed

    <...snip...>
i updmap-map: auto-generated font map files
i upmethodology: Writing specifications such as for UP-based methodologies
i uppunctlm: Always keep upright shape for some punctuation marks and Arabic numerals
    <...snip...>
```

In my set-up, it comes as part of Cygwin's [`texlive-collection-latexextra` package](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Ftexlive-collection-latexextra%2Ftexlive-collection-latexextra-20190509-1&grep=upmethodology)

**Other than checking the package, what else can I try to get `\makebackcover` recognized?**

TROUBLESHOOTING

I don't invoke any upmethodology-related files from my document source
code. If any are invoked, this might be done by the corporate
templates that I use, either directly or indirectly.  The corporate
templates reside a user-specific file subtree `texmf`, specified by a
bash environment variable: `export TEXMFHOME=texmf`.  I recursively grepped the
subtree for `upmethodology`, but found nothing; hence, `upmethodology`
must be invoked indirectly through some other package, perhaps even
from my document source file.

There are 14 file names from the **2020** Cygwin's [`texlive-collection-latexextra` package](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Ftexlive-collection-latexextra%2Ftexlive-collection-latexextra-20190509-1&grep=upmethodology) containing the string `upmethodology`:

```
usr/share/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/upmethodology/upmplainnat.bst
usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/upmethodology/upmethodology-backpage.sty
usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/upmethodology/upmethodology-code.sty
usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/upmethodology/upmethodology-document.cls
usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/upmethodology/upmethodology-document.sty
usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/upmethodology/upmethodology-extension.sty
usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/upmethodology/upmethodology-fmt.sty
usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/upmethodology/upmethodology-frontpage.sty
usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/upmethodology/upmethodology-p-common.sty
usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/upmethodology/upmethodology-spec.sty
usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/upmethodology/upmethodology-task.sty
usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/upmethodology/upmethodology-version.sty
usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/upmethodology/UPMVERSION.def
usr/share/tlpkg/tlpobj/upmethodology.tlpobj
```

I have them all.  I get the following if I `grep` them for `makebackcover`:

```
.../upmethodology-backpage.sty: \global\let\makebackcover\relax%
.../upmethodology-backpage.sty: \gdef\makebackcover{
.../upmethodology-document.cls: \ifupm@package@docclazz@addbackcover\makebackcover\fi%
```

I went back to a **2015** Cygwin installation, where I use the same user-level `texmf` and don't get the `\makebackcover` error.  I searched for the above 14 files:

```
$find /usr/share/ -name '*upmethodology*' -type f
```

I get almost the same files as above.  The only exceptions are that the 2015 install
does *not* the following 3 files:

```
usr/share/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/upmethodology/upmplainnat.bst
usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/upmethodology/UPMVERSION.def
usr/share/tlpkg/tlpobj/upmethodology.tlpobj
```

I can also `grep` the 2015 files for `makebackcover`:

```
$grep makebackcover $(find /usr/share/ -name '*upmethodology*')

.../upmethodology-backpage.sty: \global\let\makebackcover\relax%
.../upmethodology-backpage.sty: \gdef\makebackcover{
.../upmethodology-document.cls: \makebackcover%
```

The only difference with the 2020 results is the 3rd line.  The 2020
version seems to invoke `\makebackcover` conditionally.  Without
knowing how these files work, it seems that conditionaly invoking
`\makebackcover` shouldn't change whether or not it is defined.
I am reluctant to modify these system-wide files.

Instead, of mucking with system files, I `vimdiff`'d the `pdflatex`
`*.log` files for the 2015 and 2020 installations and found no obvious
signs of what could responsible for the `\makebackcover` error under
2020.  Granted, I didn't recognize many of the packages listed.  The
text "upmethodology" also appears in neither log files.  Similarly,
the text "makebackcover" doesn't appear in the 2015 log file, and
the only reason why it shows up in the 2020 log file seems to be
because it induced an error.

My next step was to track down how the 2015 install managed to define
`\makebackcover` was to seek a way to track the invocation of
packages. Based on the discussion on [LaTeX
Community](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=33235&p=111832),
I also looked for hints of where `\backpage` was set.  I found [this
code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/194539/132671) for tracking
package invocations, but it breaks with a series of errors that I
cannot decipher.  Based on David Carlisle's suggestion, I `vimdiff`'d
`pdflatex`'s terminal output from the 2015 and 2020 installations to
compare package invocations.

Unfortunately, I was wrong in assuming
that such tracking would reveal where `\makebackcover` or `\backpage` is set.
Below, I've captured the differences between the 2015 and 2020 installations
as HTML, zipped it, and encoded with `base64`. It needs to be saved to (say) `Diff.html.zip.b64`, then decoded with `base64 -d Diff.html.zip.b64 > Diff.html.zip`.

```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```

Comment: your question is very unclear, but have you loaded the package in your document? `\usepackage{upmethodology }` ?

Comment: I'm trying to find out what causes `\makebackcover` to be unrecognized. I never had this problem in a 2015 Cygwin installation. I never needed command `\usepackage{upmethodology}`. If it was invoked, then it would have been by corporate templates in the `texmf` tree. I have the exact same `texmf` tree in my 2020 Cygwin install. Just for giggles, I did put `\usepackage{upmethodology}` in my main LaTeX file, and got the error `File 'upmethodology.sty' not found`. There are many `*.sty` files above with `upmethodology` in the file name, but none named just `upmethdology.sty`.

Comment: all you have done so far is shown that you have a file somewhere in your filesystem that defines a command of that name. If you do not include that file in your document then it will not be used. It may not need to be directly loaded you may use a package that loads that indirectly but at some point you have to input it. It isn't a standard command, you presumably saw it documented somewhere which should tell you how to load it. (I haven't seen it before)

Comment: It makes sense that something needs to invoke it, but the only possibility are the corporate templates I use (which I don't understand). I use exactly the same `texmf` tree, so the corporate templates are the same. There is no `upmethodology.sty` above, which leads me to suspect that any invocation specifies one of the file names containing `upmethodology` as a substring. It's the only thing I can think of right now.

Comment: Since it appears you do have `upmethodoloy-backpage.sty` which defines the command, you could try loading that package with `\usepackage{upmethodology-backpage}`.

Comment: just show the terminal output from the run in 2015 that is working and the current one that is not, the terminal output nesting of `(` and full path names shows which files are included by which.

Comment: @Marijn: Thanks!  I actually did this first thing upon waking up (or late last night -- I can't even remember anymore). Poof! Problem solved. It's a mystery why the 2015 setup did not require this, while the 2020 installation did.  Would you care to post this as the answer? In a sense, David Carlisle was origins of this solution, as I was reflecting on his first comment above, and squaring it off with what I found in my blundering around.

Comment: @David Carlisle: Thanks, David.  The problem is now solved, based on your initial comment, and confirmed by Marijn's comment above.  About your suggestion to compare the terminal output, I had no idea that it differed from the `*.log` file from `pdflatex` -- but it does.  I am now examining the terminal output form 2015 and 2020 runs. Quite voluminous. I'll post back if I learn anything!

Comment: The output is extremely voluminous, even after cutting out the bulk of the middle part (which doesn't show package invocation).  I originally posted the html of the vimdiff after removing the bulky middle part, but even that was too big for Stack Exchange.

Comment: the only part that is relevant is the bit showing the loading or not of upmethodology files (assuming that it is those files that defined the command)  but as they don't show in the diff I assume they got loaded in the same way in both?

Comment: The `*.log` files show more detail than the terminal output; they
don't show `upmethodology`, `makebackcover`, or `backpage` -- *except*
for where `makebackcover` errors out in the 2020 installation. The
same applies to the terminal output.

Comment: How `upmethodology` gets loaded is largely the mystery. The word doesn't appear in any of the files needed by the corporate template, which all reside in my user-level `texmf` tree. I'm trying to suss out how `\makebackcover` gets defined in the 2015 installation, which might indicate something missing in the 2020 installation. Maybe I can find a way to avoid customizations to my LaTeX code, which is how I fixed it now. I want to minimize personal customizations, since the file needs to undergo an enterprise-wide process. Not everyone uses Cygwin, Tex Live, or the 2020 packages.