# Option clash for package adjustbox

Tags: errors, packages, package-options

**Problem:**

I am getting the error message `Option clash for package adjustbox.` and am wondering what could be wrong? Any advice how to figure out which of the other packages are generating this error?

**Minimal Working Example:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{menukeys}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{cellspace, graphicx, makecell}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{cellspace,tabularx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

On pc it looks like \tabwin\nobreakspace and on Mac it looks like \tab.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\documentclass[export]{article}` and then `\usepackage{adjustbox}
`.

Comment: The issue arises because  `adjustbox` is also loaded (indirectly) by `tikz`. Either issue the instruction `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` *before* `\usepackage{tikz}` or, better still, follow Harish's advice to provide the global option `export` to the `\documentclass` option. That way, you won't have to worry about how to sequence the loading of these two packages.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Mico and for the solution @HarishKumar

Comment: Are you aware you're trying to load `cellspace` and `graphicx` twice? (Not that it would matter much but things like this just clutter the preamble…)

Comment: @clemens Would you care to elaborate and suggest what I could do to improve the preamble?

Comment: @kexxcream you could check if you load any packages twice and remove the second one. Then I'd also try to group package loading a bit thematically so it's easier to spot which packages are loaded and what they're for.

Comment: A better duplicate perhaps is [Package options and \RequirePackage: order of commands and option conflicts?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64599/package-options-and-requirepackage-order-of-commands-and-option-conflicts).

Answer (score 3):

`adjustbox` is explicitly loaded by `menukeys`, without any options. You can either set the option as an option to `\documentclass`, or use

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{export}{adjustbox}
```

in the preamble. Also, needless to load `adjustbox` if you load `menukeys`.

Comment aside, don't load  `cellspace` twice.

Comment: It is not needless to load `adjustbox` explicitly. The fact that the current version of `menukeys` loads `adjustbox` is just an implementation detail, which can change in later versions.